# get response from FB Api JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

i try to get a function return in combination with facebook api reqeust.

```
var g_ret = true;

function uploadImagesFbCounter(anz){
    var gid='';
    $("div[id ^= 'gallerydetail']").each(function (i) {
        gid = this.id.split('-');
        gid = parseInt(gid[1]);
    })
    if(gid==0) return true;

    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        //console.log(response);
        var uid = response.id;

        if(!anz){
            g_ret = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "api/gallerie_anz_speich.php",
                data: "uid="+uid+"&op=get&gid="+gid
            });

            if(g_ret.response >= 20)    {
                g_ret = false;
            }
        }   else    {
            g_ret = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "api/gallerie_anz_speich.php",
                data: "uid="+uid+"&op=set&gid="+gid
            });
            //console.log(g_ret.response);
            g_ret = '<span style="padding:0 5px;">Noch '+(20-g_ret.response)+'Fotos</span>';
            console.log(g_ret);
        }
    });

    return g_ret;
}
```

what ever I do, i get an empty response.... please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the user information from Facebook's servers is asynchronous. This means, any code you write after `FB.api()` does not wait for Facebook to respond. Your browser is not blocked just to wait for Facebook's servers. This is the same concept as AJAX, which I believe you are familiar with because I see you use it in your code.

The common way to "get a return value" from an asynchronous server request is to use a callback function.

```
function uploadImagesFbCounter(anz, onSuccess){
    var gid='';
    $("div[id ^= 'gallerydetail']").each(function (i) {
        gid = this.id.split('-');
        gid = parseInt(gid[1]);
    })
    if(gid==0) return true;

    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        //console.log(response);
        var uid = response.id;

        if(!anz){
            g_ret = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "api/gallerie_anz_speich.php",
                data: "uid="+uid+"&op=get&gid="+gid
            });

            if(g_ret.response >= 20)    {
                g_ret = false;
            }
        }   else    {
            g_ret = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "api/gallerie_anz_speich.php",
                data: "uid="+uid+"&op=set&gid="+gid
            });
            //console.log(g_ret.response);
            g_ret = '<span style="padding:0 5px;">Noch '+(20-g_ret.response)+'Fotos</span>';
            console.log(g_ret);
        }

        onSuccess(g_ret);
    });

}


uploadImagesFbCounter(
    whateverAnzIs, 
    function(g_ret) {
        console.info(g_ret);
    }
);
```

Comment: You also need your $.ajax success callbacks to call onSuccess. I don't know jQuery, so you'll have to figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

The API you're using is **asynchronous**.  You can't return a value from your function like that; it's just impossible in such a situation.

Instead, write your API so that its clients pass it a callable function. Inside the Facebook API callback, you can call that function and pass it that "g_ret" string.

```
function uploadImagesFbCounter(anz, callback){
  // ...
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    // ...
    callback(g_ret);
  });
}
```

Then when you call your function, instead of:

```
var result = uploadImagesFbCounter( whatever );
// ... do something with result ...
```

you'd do this:

```
uploadImagesFbCounter( whatever, function( result ) {
  // ... do something with result ...
});
```

Comment: I just updated the answer with the basic idea.  I'll add a little more.